# How do you point out that a person is incompetent without exposing yourself to the risk of being sued?

Tags: management, termination

How do you point out that a person is incompetent without exposing yourself to the risk of being sued? Let's say that your engineering lead is really terrible, and can't coach (has a really poor understanding of engineering or software engineering in general), can't hire people properly (hire juniors who pretend to be seniors), how do you point it out to the rest of the management or upper management without exposing yourself to the risk of being sued for defamation? I heard you can get sued even if you state your opinion and you truly believe that your opinion is the truth.

Comment: Have you ever heard of someone being sued for expressing an opinion within the workplace like that?

Comment: "being sued" is not a globally valid truth. I'm sure there are countries where you can be beaten to death for it. Doesn't mean that is normal or that applies to the country you reside in. Please add a country tag.

Comment: It feels like you have a valid problem here (your lead is not great) but have jumped straight to an ultra-specific part of that (how can you not be sued). What would you like to achieve by saying your lead needs to improve?

Comment: This is just a functional re-post of your question on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79600/how-can-you-say-a-developer-is-bad-without-being-subject-to-a-defamation-lawsuit)

Answer (score 3):

You don't run around and tell people your personal opinion of colleagues. You share objective and measurable metrics with your managers, and inform them of any blockers you have.

If there is a problem with a colleague, subordinate or manager of yours, AND it's blocking your success, you can report that. In a constructive and objective manner. No finger pointing, no "he said, she said".

If there is something wrong with someone but it does not prevent you from doing your work, keep quiet. It's none of your business.

Answer (score 1):

By not putting it in writing you greatly reduce the chance of legal repercussions.

Or if you have no fear of legal repercussions because you can prove your slander is true.

Having said that bad mouthing a colleague can give you a lot more problems than legal repercussions ever would. So it shouldn't be done without analysing the potential outcomes good and bad.